# Rethrow Exception from slack api Response payload, or handle it appropriately

Tags: kotlin, slack

The Slack conversations.join api returns a Slack API Exception (part of Response Body - i.e ConversationsJoinResponse object returned from Slack Library response) when it is unable to join a slack channel for some reason , it is sent as a part of API Response object which is a ConversationsJoinResponse object .

I have used this Api which returns the Slack Library Response object.

Documentation - https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.join

Api - https://slack.com/api/conversations.join

IMHO it would be better to throw the exception I received from the Api itself.

So I am trying to rethrow the same exception I get from the slack library and returns the error message in Response object returned by the library i.e ConversationsJoinResponse object.

Would this be the right way to handle the exception where the SlackApiException class takes a Request Body and a message.

```
logger.error("Error Joining Channel - $channelId : ${response.error}")
throw SlackApiException(
  Response.Builder().code(400).request(
    Request.Builder().url("https://slack.com/api/conversations.join").build())
    .message(response.error).build(),
  response.error
)
```

Any help with figuring the appropriate way to handle the Api Response is appreciated.

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you’re asking. surely you’ve heard of try-catch

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar , The error is a part of the Api Response Payload. Are you suggesting it is possible to catch that.

Comment: The response may give you additional detail about the error, but you’re getting a non-200 response code, aren’t you? All HTTP clients recognize that and either throw an exception or return a custom error object. No one can help you unless you elaborate and show your code.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The response gives me SlackApiException and the Response object is a ConversationsJoinResponse. I tagged it with slack as well.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The rest of the code is unrelated to the issue at hand. What do you think is missing or needs to be added. Do ask for the relevant details which may be missing ?